# Save Combobox selected value in XML File and than load it again on button click using C#

Tags: c#, xml

so I have a WPF App which is made dynamically with the information from XML File and I have a ComboBox where I can select items which I need, than I need to save it in another XML File (it works with TextBox and CheckBox) and I tried it with .SelectedValue and .SelectedItem but I get an error by the serializer as I klick on Save, it says:

System.InvalidOperationException: "An error occurred while generating the XML document."

Can someone tell me why is there an error and suggest me something different which I can try to use?

Here is my Code for Save Button and Open(Load) Button:

```
private void FileSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new SaveFileDialog()
            {
                Filter = "XML File | *.xml"
            };
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == false)
                return;

            var viewModel = DataContext as MainViewModel;
            var projectData = new List<ProjectData>();

            foreach (var control in _allControls)
            {
                if (control.Value is CheckBox checkBoxControl)
                {
                    var projectDataItem = new ProjectData()
                    {
                        Type = "Checkbox",
                        Content = checkBoxControl.IsChecked,
                        Title = checkBoxControl.Tag as string,
                    };
                    projectData.Add(projectDataItem);
                }

                if (control.Value is TextBox textBoxControl)
                {
                    var projectDataItem = new ProjectData()
                    {
                        Type = "Text",
                        Content = textBoxControl.Text,
                        Title = textBoxControl.Tag as string,
                    };
                    projectData.Add(projectDataItem);
                }

                if (control.Value is ComboBox comboBoxControl)
                {
                    var projectDataItem = new ProjectData()
                    {
                        Type = "Dropbox",
                        Content = comboBoxControl.SelectedValue,
                        Title = comboBoxControl.Tag as string,
                    };
                    projectData.Add(projectDataItem);
                }
            }

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ProjectData>));
            var writer = new StreamWriter(dialog.FileName);

            serializer.Serialize(writer, projectData);
            writer.Close();
        }

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void FileOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == false)
                return;

            var readFile = new FileStream(dialog.FileName, FileMode.Open);
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ProjectData>));

            var data = (List<ProjectData>)serializer.Deserialize(readFile);

            var textBoxes = FindVisualChilds<TextBox>(this);
            var checkBoxes = FindVisualChilds<CheckBox>(this);

            var comboBoxes = FindVisualChilds<ComboBox>(this);


            foreach (var projectData in data)
            {
                if (projectData.Type == "Text")
                {
                    var textBox = textBoxes.FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Tag == projectData.Title);
                    if (textBox != null)
                    {
                        textBox.Text = projectData.Content as string;
                    }
                }

                if (projectData.Type == "Checkbox")
                {
                    var checkBox = checkBoxes.FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Tag == projectData.Title);
                    if (checkBox != null)
                    {
                        if (projectData.Content is bool checkedValue)
                        {
                            checkBox.IsChecked = checkedValue;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //if (projectData.Type == "Dropbox")
                //{
                //    var comboBox = comboBoxes.FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Tag == projectData.Title);
                //    if (comboBox != null)
                //    {
                //        if (projectData.Content is bool selectedValue)
                //        {
                //            comboBox.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
                //        }
                //    }
                //}
            }

            readFile.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.SelectedValue.ToString();`

Comment: It says: System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: That error should only show up if your combobox has nothing selected. Try setting a breakpoint there when debugging to see if your SelectedValue is null or not.